# How to filter product collection using array of attributes and values

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to filter the productCollection using attribute and values arrays, but it it showing error, here below is my code. Please, let me know how it can be done...

```
$requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParam('requestParams');
$shoppingBy = $requestParams["shoppingBy"];

$attributeCodes = array_keys($shoppingBy);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
->load($requestParams['categoryId'])
->getProductCollection();

foreach($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
    $attributeValue = $shoppingBy[$attributeCode];
    $filter = array('attribute' => $attributeCode, 'in' => $attributeValue);
    $productCollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edited:

I am not sure 100%  to use **in**  for all attribute .Checkout this link for magento collection operator and more details https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Using+Magento+1.x+collections

**Change:**

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
->load($requestParams['categoryId'])
->getProductCollection();
```

**to**

```
$category= Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
->load($requestParams['categoryId']);
$productCollection =$category->getProductCollection();
```

**And Change**

```
foreach($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
    $attributeValue = $shoppingBy[$attributeCode];
    $filter = array('attribute' => $attributeCode, 'in' => $attributeValue);
    $productCollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

**to**

```
$filter=array();
foreach($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
    $attributeValue = $shoppingBy[$attributeCode];
    $filter[] = array('attribute' => $attributeCode, 'in' => $attributeValue);
}

$productCollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
```

**use :** `echo $productCollection->getSelect()->__toString();` for getting the query string..

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.

Comment: It is not having any product in its collection

Comment: i guss that your issue at in condition,Please check  poroperly

Comment: The data I have sent from AJAX here is JSON, and somewhat looks like this =>           

{"requestParams":{"productCount":8,"categoryId":"6","sortOption":"2672","sortDirection":"asc","productLimit":8,"shoppingBy":{"no_of_poles":["3 Pole"]}}}.         I have even logged the in values and they are proper. The logged value is Array([0] => 3 Pole(